# VB.NET Tool To List And Change Users Groups On Active Directory

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a tool to list and change users group on active directory based on groups that manager has control. I'm stuck on listing function, and it keep getting me this error:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
> Hresult=0x80072032   Message=Invalid distinguished name (DN) syntax specified
>
> Line: Dim searchResults As Search...

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click

        Dim managerID As String
        managerID = mngID.Text
        Dim employeeID As String
        employeeID = empID.Text
        Dim emptybox
        emptybox = mngID.Text.Length
        If emptybox < 8 Then
            MsgBox("ManagerID Inválido")
        End If
        Dim emptybox2
        emptybox2 = empID.Text.Length
        If emptybox2 < 8 Then
            MsgBox("EmployeeID Inválido")
        End If

        If emptybox = 8 Then
            Dim domain = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
            Dim user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, managerID)
            Dim userDN
            userDN = user.DistinguishedName

            Dim ADEntry As New DirectoryEntry
            ADEntry.Path = "LDAP://domain/CN:Users;DC:domain"
            Dim Groups As New Collection
            Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(ADEntry)
            Dim arrList As New ArrayList()

            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(DistinguisedName=" & userDN & "))"
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("MemberOf")

            Dim searchResults As SearchResultCollection = mySearcher.FindAll()
            If searchResults.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("ManagerID inválido2")
            End If
            If searchResults.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim group As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults(0).Path)
                    For Each member As Object In group.Properties("MemberOf")
                        groupbox.Items.Add(member)
                    Next
                End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the error message is not in English.

Comment: it is in English now...

Answer (score 0):

**Your Error**

Error 0x80072032 - ERROR_DS_INVALID_DN_SYNTAX
An invalid 'dn' syntax has been specified

Here's something to get you going.

**Example VB Script To Connect to Active Directory**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Imports System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Security.Permissions
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

    Public Function EnumerateDomains() As ArrayList
        Dim alDomains As New ArrayList()
        Dim currentForrest As Forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest()
        Dim myDomains As DomainCollection = currentForrest.Domains
        For Each objDomain As Domain In myDomains
            alDomains.Add(objDomain.Name)
        Next
        Return alDomains
    End Function

    Public Function EumerateDomainUsers() As ArrayList
        Dim domainUsers As New ArrayList()
        Dim usr As String
        'Dim fqdns As String = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Dim fqdns As String = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text
        Dim adStrng As String = "LDAP://" & fqdns
        Dim adEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetObject(adStrng)
        Dim searcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(adEntry)
        searcher.Sort.PropertyName = "cn"
        Dim results As SearchResultCollection
        Dim result As SearchResult
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
        results = searcher.FindAll
        For Each result In results
            usr = result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("cn").Value
            domainUsers.Add(usr)
        Next
        Return domainUsers
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake and should be "DistinguishedName" instead of "DistinguisedName":

```vb
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(DistinguishedName=" & userDN & "))"
```

Comment: Didn't see this mistake...
Already fixed it, but the error persist